# How do I resolve those errors

Tags: git, merge, commit

Here is the session log of my github shell:

```
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app [master +258 ~0 -0 | +85 ~23 -269 !]> git commit
U       dbinterface/Debug/dbinterface.Build.CppClean.log
U       dbinterface/Debug/dbinterface.log
U       dbinterface/ReadMe.txt
U       dbinterface/database.h
U       dbinterface/dbinterface.sln
U       dbinterface/dbinterface.vcxproj
U       dbinterface/dbinterface.vcxproj.filters
U       dbinterface/dbinterface.vcxproj.user
U       dbinterface/stdafx.cpp
U       dbinterface/stdafx.h
U       dbinterface/targetver.h
error: commit is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app [master +258 ~0 -0 | +85 ~23 -269 !]> git merge
error: merge is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app [master +258 ~0 -0 | +85 ~23 -269 !]> git merge --no-commit
error: merge is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

It looks like I can't commit because I didn't merge, but merge also failed.

So how do I resolve it?

Comment: The message says very clearly: **Fix them up in the work tree, and then use  git add/rm**. Not `git merge`, `git add` or `git rm`. Each file that has a `U` next to it needs to be edited to resolve the conflicts and then `git add` it.

Comment: @meagar, there are 2 files in the dbinterface/Debug directory. Can I exclude them? Because they will be overwritten with every build during development. Or I will have to fix them and then add them to .gitignore? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge is just a commit with multiple parents. A merge conflict works like any other unfinished work-in-progress. Any files which were successfully merged will already be staged (added). Any files where the merge failed will not be staged; they will be partially merged with markers (`<<<<<`) showing the conflicting lines. A `git status` will show you this and give you instructions.

Do what you'd normally do to finish a commit: edit the files which are unstaged to fix the conflicts and `add` them. When you've added everything and your tests pass, commit.

More information can be found in the [Basic Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) section of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).